# Is OpenCV's Cholesky function available in python?

Tags: python, opencv, linear-algebra, decomposition

OpenCV has a function to compute the Cholesky decomposition
http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gsc.tab=0

I've been able to use it in C++.  I would like to use it in Python.

I tried

```
import cv2
cv2.Cholesky(A)  #assume A is a numpy array
```

but it didn't work.

Is OpenCV's Cholesky function available in python? If yes, how do I access/use it?

Comment: According to the description of [how the Python bindings are generated](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html#gsc.tab=0) the function declaration should contains `CV_EXPORTS_W`, however it [only contains `CV_EXPORTS`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/904381c602043270fc864b29dd4749c9c75effbd/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/hal.hpp#L223). That would lead me to believe there is no binding generated for it. You could probably use the function through ctypes?